# How to exclude a term from a taxonomy post count function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that displays the post count of any terms for its taxonomy anywhere i want to show it and it works great but i would like to change this up a bit to completely exclude the post count of any post that has a certain term added to it, let's call that "state". So if a post has "state" added to it, i would like the function to not include the count of that post in any terms within the taxonomy.

```
function get_city_count( $taxonomy = 'countries', $term = '', $args = [] )
{
if ( !$term )
    return false;

if ( $term !== 'all' ) {
    if ( !is_array( $term ) ) {
        $term = filter_var( $term, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    } else {
        $term = filter_var_array( $term, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    }
}

if ( $taxonomy !== 'countries' ) { $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) return false;
}

if ( $args ) { if ( !is_array )  return false; } $defaults = [ 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'fields' => 'ids' ];
if ( $term !== 'all' ) { $defaults['tax_query'] = [ [ 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'terms' => $term ] ]; }

$combined_args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
$q = new WP_Query( $combined_args );

return $q->found_posts;
}
```